# Why consecutive printf() not giving any output to terminal emulator (previous one did)?

Tags: c

I tried to implement a merge sort algorithm in C (learning) but during debugging found strange behaviour of the code for me. It compiles ok (with gcc). 
However `printf()` function behaves in a strange way.

In the below code, line 54 `printf` gives output but then next `printf` function in line 58 does not. I know there is also some bug in the code (like infinte loop) but that's not the point now.

I do not understand why there is no possibility to get `printf` output after line 54 (in function `main()`).
I also tried to add another `printf` in line 55 but without success. I ran the executable on openSUSE Leap Linux.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Rider {
    FILE *fp;
    const char *filename;
    int curr;
    int next;
    int eor;
};
void set_rider(const char *filename, const char *mode, struct Rider *rider_name) {
    if ((rider_name->fp = fopen(filename,mode)) == NULL)
        printf("File open for \"%s\" failed!\n",filename), exit(1);
    rider_name->filename = filename;
    rider_name->curr = 0;
    rider_name->next = 0;
    rider_name->eor = 0;
}
void close_rider(struct Rider *rider_name) {
    if (rider_name->fp != NULL)
        if((fclose(rider_name->fp)) != 0)
            printf("Closing of \"%s\" failed!\n",rider_name->filename);

}
void show_sequence(struct Rider *rider_name) {
    printf("%s:\n",rider_name->filename);
    while((rider_name->curr = fgetc(rider_name->fp))!= EOF) 
        printf("%d,", rider_name->curr);
    printf("\n");
}
void copy_run(struct Rider *src, struct Rider *dest) {
    if (src->eor == 1) {
        fputc(src->next,dest->fp);
        src->eor = 0;
    }
    while (src->eor != 1) {
        if((src->curr = fgetc(src->fp)) != EOF) {
            fputc(src->curr,dest->fp);
            if((src->next = fgetc(src->fp)) < src->curr)
                src->eor = 1;
            else fputc(src->next,src->fp);
        }
    }
}


int main(void) {
    int i = 0, seed=5, run_count = 0;

    struct Rider r_tmp, r_a, r_b, r_c;
    set_rider("c.txt", "w+", &r_c);

    /* create initial pseudo-random sequence and store in file */
    printf("Generated sequence %s:\n", r_c.filename); //this prinftf() works
    while ( i < 20) {

        if (seed < 256) {
            printf("%d,", seed); //this printf() not working already
            fputc(seed, r_c.fp);
            i++;
        }
        seed = (31*seed)% 997 + 5;
    }
    close_rider(&r_c); 

    while ( run_count != 1) {
        run_count = 0;
    /* PHASE distribute c to a, b */ 
    set_rider("c.txt","r+",&r_c);
    set_rider("a.txt","w+",&r_a);
    set_rider("b.txt","w+",&r_b);

    while (r_c.curr !=EOF) {
        copy_run(&r_c, &r_a);
        if (r_c.eor != 1)
            copy_run(&r_c,&r_b);
    }

   /* 
    r_c.curr = fgetc(r_c.fp);

    while ( r_c.curr != EOF) {
        if ( r_c.eor == 1) {
            r_tmp = r_a, r_a = r_b, r_b = r_tmp; 
            fputc( r_c.curr, r_a.fp);
            r_c.eor = 0;
        }
        else fputc( r_c.curr, r_a.fp);
        r_c.next = fgetc(r_c.fp);
        if ( r_c.next < r_c.curr) 
            r_c.eor = 1;
        r_c.curr = r_c.next;
    }
   */ 

    /*print the results */
    /*close files to reset pointers esp. r_a.fp and r_b.fp which could be swapped */
    /*maybe can be done without file closing.. */
    close_rider(&r_a);
    close_rider(&r_b);
    close_rider(&r_c);

    set_rider("c.txt","r+",&r_c);
    set_rider("a.txt","r+",&r_a);
    set_rider("b.txt","r+",&r_b);


show_sequence(&r_c);
show_sequence(&r_a);
show_sequence(&r_b);


    /*close files */
    close_rider(&r_a);
    close_rider(&r_b);
    close_rider(&r_c);


    /* PHASE merge a, b into c */

    /* open files for merge */
    set_rider("c.txt","w+",&r_c);
    set_rider("a.txt","r+",&r_a);
    set_rider("b.txt","r+",&r_b);

    r_a.curr = fgetc(r_a.fp);
    r_b.curr = fgetc(r_b.fp);

while ( (r_a.curr != EOF) && (r_b.curr != EOF)) {
    /*merge one run from each side */
    while ((r_a.eor != 1) && (r_b.eor != 1)) { 
        if ( r_a.curr <= r_b.curr ) {
            fputc(r_a.curr, r_c.fp);
            r_a.next = fgetc(r_a.fp);
            r_a.eor = r_a.next < r_a.curr ? 1 : 0;
            r_a.curr = r_a.next;
        }
        else {
            fputc(r_b.curr, r_c.fp);
            r_b.next = fgetc(r_b.fp);
            r_b.eor = r_b.next < r_b.curr ? 1 : 0;
            r_b.curr = r_b.next;
        }
    }
    /* copy tails till eor */
    while ( r_a.eor != 1) {
        fputc(r_a.curr, r_c.fp);
        r_a.next = fgetc(r_a.fp);
        r_a.eor = r_a.next < r_a.curr ? 1 : 0;
        r_a.curr = r_a.next;
    }
    r_a.eor = 0;
    while ( r_b.eor != 1) {
        fputc(r_b.curr, r_c.fp);
        r_b.next = fgetc(r_b.fp);
        r_b.eor = r_b.next < r_b.curr ? 1 : 0;
        r_b.curr = r_b.next;
    }
    r_b.eor = 0;
    run_count++;
}
/* copy tails till EOF */
if ( r_a.curr !=EOF)
    run_count++;
if (r_b.curr != EOF)
    run_count++;
while ( r_a.curr != EOF) {
    fputc(r_a.curr, r_c.fp);
    r_a.curr = fgetc(r_a.fp);
}
while ( r_b.curr != EOF) {
    fputc(r_b.curr, r_c.fp);
    r_b.curr = fgetc(r_b.fp);
}



    rewind(r_c.fp);

   show_sequence(&r_c);
    /*close files */
    close_rider(&r_a);
    close_rider(&r_b);
    close_rider(&r_c);
}

    set_rider("c.txt","r", &r_c); 
    printf("Final :\n");
    show_sequence(&r_c);
    close_rider(&r_c);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure output is seen right after you call a buffered I/O function, you need to flush the corresponding stream. For instance, with `fflush(stdout);`.

In any case, you need to minimize your problem and/or use a debugger, specially since you know there are other problems at the same time.

Comment: @milan: you'll find that everything works more smoothly if you send error messages and debugging output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. That's what it's there for, and for that reason it is usually unbuffered.

Comment: @rici: it is valuable information. Thank you. I used to use printf() for in-code debugging info printing not knowing stderr is better for it. Is there any rule when printf() will not print out and wait for fflush or it depends?

Comment: @milan: no rule, but in the usual implementation `stdout` will buffer until a newline is printed ("line-buffering") if it is attached to terminal. If you redirect to a file or even a pipe, it will buffer until it accumulates "enough" data ("block-buffering"). `stderr` is normally unbuffered and output is immediate. `stdout` should only be used fir "normal" data output, since you might want to pass it through a pipe or save it in a file. Use `stderr` for *all* interactive, unstructured output: command prompts, warnings, debugging information, etc.

Comment: `fflush` on `stdout`  is not a problem, by the way. If you saw a warning, it probably related to `fflush(stdin)`, which is invalid on many systems and has nothing to do with buffered *output*. Regardless, you shouldn't need to fflush stdout if you use stdout and stderr correctlym